# How to prevent unescape

Tags: javascript

I need to submit the code *with* the percentage, but the jQuery keep unescaping it:

> jQuery.post('LINK',{'content':'%74%65%73%74%69%6E%67'});

It must be sent like this:

> %74%65%73%74%69%6E%67

But it's send like this:

> testing

Comment: try to `encodeURIComponent('%74%65%73%74%69%6E%67')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `encodeURIComponent(..)` to properly escape the percentile characters.

```
jQuery.post('LINK',{'content':encodeURIComponent('%74%65%73%74%69%6E%67')})
```